# Cannot use more than 2 monitors at a time

Tags: xorg, xrandr, manjaro, multi-monitor

I recently purchased a new monitor and adapter cord in order to have 3 monitors connected to my desktop

However, nothing will display on the third monitor

I tried switch the cords around and figured out that the monitor and the adapter both work, but for some reason my system will not display more than 2 monitors at a time, as I was able to get the new monitor to work by just disconnected one of my other two monitors, but reconnecting them will make them no longer display

I booted into both Windows and Ubuntu and both could display on all 3 monitors, so I know it is not a hardware issue or one with Linux in general, but something about my install

Here is some info

My main two monitors are DVI and an HDMI (Through a HDMI to DVI adapter) while the new third one is a Mini-DisplayPort to DVI adapter

This is the output of "xrandr --verbose"

---

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3280 x 1050, maximum 16384 x 16384
 DisplayPort-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x55
    Timestamp:  1395416
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      1 2 0 3 4 5
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
EDID: 
    00ffffffffffff0022f0172901010101
    0f140103802917782edc55a359489e24
    115054a1080081c08140818001010101
    010101010101662156aa51001e30468f
    33009ae61000001e000000fd00324c18
    5311000a202020202020000000fc0048
    502053313933310a20202020000000ff
    0033435130313533474e330a202000e4
TearFree: auto 
    supported: off, on, auto
output_csc: bypass 
    supported: bypass, tvrgb, ycbcr601, ycbcr709
audio: auto 
    supported: off, on, auto
scaling mode: None 
    supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
dither: off 
    supported: off, on
underscan vborder: 0 
    range: (0, 128)
underscan hborder: 0 
    range: (0, 128)
underscan: off 
    supported: off, on, auto
coherent: 1 
    range: (0, 1)
  1366x768 (0x5a) 85.500MHz +HSync +VSync +preferred
    h: width  1366 start 1436 end 1579 total 1792 skew    0 clock  47.71KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  774 total  798           clock  59.79Hz
  1280x1024 (0x5b) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
    v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x960 (0x5c) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
    v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x5d) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
    v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x5e) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x5f) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x60) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
    v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x61) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
    v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Identifier: 0x56
Timestamp:  1395416
Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
Clones:    
CRTCs:      1 2 0 3 4 5
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
TearFree: auto 
    supported: off, on, auto
output_csc: bypass 
    supported: bypass, tvrgb, ycbcr601, ycbcr709
audio: auto 
    supported: off, on, auto
scaling mode: None 
    supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
dither: off 
    supported: off, on
underscan vborder: 0 
    range: (0, 128)
underscan hborder: 0 
    range: (0, 128)
underscan: off 
    supported: off, on, auto
coherent: 1 
    range: (0, 1)
HDMI-0 connected 1600x900+0+103 (0x62) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm
Identifier: 0x57
Timestamp:  1395416
Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
Brightness: 1.0
Clones:    
CRTC:       2
CRTCs:      1 2 0 3 4 5
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
EDID: 
    00ffffffffffff000472730074b24090
    04130103802c1978eade95a3544c9926
    0f5054bfef80714f8140818081c08100
    010101010101312e40006284223058a8
    3500bbf91000001d000000fd00374b1f
    500c000a202020202020000000ff004c
    45563043303037343031300a000000fc
    0058323033480a2020202020202000ba
TearFree: auto 
    supported: off, on, auto
output_csc: bypass 
    supported: bypass, tvrgb, ycbcr601, ycbcr709
audio: auto 
    supported: off, on, auto
scaling mode: None 
    supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
dither: off 
    supported: off, on
underscan vborder: 0 
    range: (0, 128)
underscan hborder: 0 
    range: (0, 128)
underscan: off 
    supported: off, on, auto
coherent: 1 
    range: (0, 1)
  1600x900 (0x62) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
    h: width  1600 start 1688 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
    v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
  1280x1024 (0x5b) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
    v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x960 (0x5c) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
    v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x800 (0x63) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
    v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0x64) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
    v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
 1280x720 (0x5d) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
    v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x65) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
    v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x66) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x5e) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  832x624 (0x67) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
    v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0x68) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
    v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x69) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x5f) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x6a) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  640x480 (0x6b) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
    v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x6c) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
    v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0x6d) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
    v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
  640x480 (0x60) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
    v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x61) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
    v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
DVI-0 connected primary 1680x1050+1600+0 (0x6e) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
Identifier: 0x58
Timestamp:  1395416
Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
Brightness: 1.0
Clones:    
CRTC:       0
CRTCs:      1 2 0 3 4 5
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
EDID: 
    00ffffffffffff0010ac15d053315035
    08120103802f1e78ee8f30a355499827
    145054a54b00714f8180010101010101
    0101010101017c2e90a0601a1e403020
    3600d9281100001a000000ff004b5533
    313138324b355031530a000000fd0038
    4b1e530e000a202020202020000000fc
    0044454c4c20453232385746500a0099
TearFree: auto 
    supported: off, on, auto
output_csc: bypass 
    supported: bypass, tvrgb, ycbcr601, ycbcr709
load detection: 1 
    range: (0, 1)
audio: auto 
    supported: off, on, auto
scaling mode: None 
    supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
dither: off 
    supported: off, on
underscan vborder: 0 
    range: (0, 128)
underscan hborder: 0 
    range: (0, 128)
underscan: off 
    supported: off, on, auto
coherent: 1 
    range: (0, 1)
  1680x1050 (0x6e) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
    h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
    v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x1024 (0x6f) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
    v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x5b) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
    v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1152x864 (0x64) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
    v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x65) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
    v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x5e) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x69) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x5f) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x6b) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
    v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x60) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
    v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x61) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
    v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
```

---

If I attempt to manually set the mode of the monitor with "xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --mode 1366x768"
I receive the error "xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed"

Attempting the same thing with arandr gives the same error

While writing this question, I noticed that this was being spit into my open terminal window at random times

```
[  1525.72 ] error    9 BadDrawable  request   14 minor    0 serial 2715850: "BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)"
 glx_bind_pixmap(0x03058ae6): Failed to query Pixmap info.
 win_paint_win(0x04600049): Failed to bind texture. Expect troubles.
 win_paint_win(0x04600049): Missing painting data. This is a bad sign.
```

Here is my system info

```
Linux Hal9000 4.9.28-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun May 14 13:32:39 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My GPU is a Radeon 7770, and I'm using the free drivers.

Comment: Try setting up all 3 screens with moderate solutions (maybe 800x600 or something like that) at moderate frame rates, to test if you run into any maximal framebuffer size or VRAM access timing limit issues.

Comment: After changing my main 2 monitors resolution to 1024x768, I was able to get the third monitor to work, so it does seem like I am hitting some kind of limit

Comment: This smells definitely like you are hitting a limit. Experiment a bit until you found resolutions that suit your needs. To find out the limit rules, one probably has to read the source code of the drivers.

Comment: Would this be a hardware limit of my graphics card or an artificial limit in the driver?

Comment: Usually a hardware limit of your graphics card that's enforced by the driver. Sometimes the driver is wrong, because it applies limits that apply to other models, but that's very rarely the case.